# How to pass values of dynamic HTML form field to my Flask application

Tags: python, flask

My webpage has dynamic form fields. User can add or remove input field. How can I pass the form value to my script, when I'm not sure how many fields it's going to be?.

[Here's the form Field, where user can add or remove year to the field before submitting the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK3ue.png)

Comment: But where's your code?

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is more about flask or javascript

Comment: I'm asking about FLASK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know how many fields it's going to be. Give all the fields the same HTML `name` attribute, and the data can be accessed in Flask via `request.form.getlist(fieldname)`.